# PhpMyAdmin not working since update to MAMP 5.0

Tags: phpmyadmin, mamp-pro

Since my update to MAMP Pro 5.0.3, phpMyAdmin does not work anymore. I just get the "Index of /phpMyAdmin"...
I have tried to change port, but i had to come back to my config to make my websites running. It is port 3306 for MySQL.
I have tried to restart, re-install phpMyAdmin, re-install MAMP Pro, but issue is still there.
The connexion from my websites to MySQL is ok and websites works. But i can't make phpMyAdmin running... 
Any advices ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this issue today too, and resolved it with the following steps:

1. Download the [latest stable version of phpMyAdmin](https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.8.3/phpMyAdmin-4.8.3-all-languages.zip)
2. Back up your old `phpMyAdmin` directory located at `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/phpMyAdmin`
3. Unzip the new downloaded version of phpMyAdmin - mine was called `phpMyAdmin-4.8.3-all-languages`
4. Move this folder to `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/`. You should now have 2 phpMyAdmin folders in there - your original folder, `phpMyAdmin` and the new folder, `phpMyAdmin-4.8.3-all-languages`
5. Copy the `config.inc.php` file from your **original** `phpMyAdmin` folder to the new one - you will have to confirm it's OK to overwrite - but please make sure you are definitely not overwriting your old one
6. Rename your original `phpMyAdmin` folder to `phpMyAdmin.old` (or whatever you want) and rename the new one to `phpMyAdmin`.
7. Restart the MAMP servers. Navigate to `http://localhost/phpMyAdmin` or http://localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin` if you are using default ports, and you should have your phpMyAdmin back.

Comment: This strategy worked for me, thank you. I would suggest an edit to change the link in the first step to the following (currently points directly to an outdated version), but the queue is full:

https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, seeing only Index (not the actual web-based phpMyAdmin tool) after upgrading MAMP PRO from 4.x to 5.x. I saw the above solution but didn't try it. Support said this probably happened because during the upgrade phpMyAdmin was not correctly or fully copied over. Their solution worked:

1. Stop your servers and quit MAMP PRO. (Your phpMyAdmin is located in /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/phpMyAdmin)
2. Rename this folder to phpMyAdmin_bak
3. Start MAMP PRO, start your servers
4. You should have a new /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/phpMyAdmin
5. All good again.